# Evidence that stationary masses in space actually attract each other

Tags: experimental-physics, newtonian-gravity, mass, reference-frames

I'm finding it rather difficult to find experimental evidence that two stationary masses in space (unaffected by external massive bodies or gravities) actually attract one another. For moving masses, this is abundantly clear (planets, asteroids, etc.), but who has actually tried to measure forces of attraction between objects stationary in space with respect to the Sun, and has found through experimentation that the hypothesis of gravity being proportional to motionless masses is true?

I'm aware of the [Cavendish experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment), however, this experiment is not what I'm looking for because the two balls are moving with the Earth, so they are not completely without motion with respect to the Sun. Relative to each other, the balls are stationary, but I am looking for an experiment conducted where there is no motion in the massive objects relative to the Sun.

Comment: There is no absolute reference frame, so one cannot speak of things that are not moving in space. Everything is moving in some reference frame and stationary in some other. In each reference frame, the laws of physics must be the same.

Comment: @qweilun What about the center of the universe? Could that be considered as a valid reference frame?

Comment: The universe has no definable center. You might try to argue for the center of the observable universe, but this does not help us because all observations have shown the universe to be isotropic and homogeneous at the largest distance scales.

Comment: If you sent a rocket up in space to avoid moving "with" the Earth, then someone could object that you are still orbiting the center of the galaxy.  If you sent a super deep space probe to leave the galaxy that would take a very very long time, and you'd still be in the thrall of the nearest supercluster.  Eventually you realize there isn't much basis for saying whether you are at rest or moving, only that there is relative motion or relative rest.

Comment: if my last comment seemed rather pointless, it's because i meant to say: take a point at the edge of the observable universe. All evidence suggests that from that vantage point, everything will look just about the same as it does from Earth. This is how we have no real sense of a center of the universe.

Comment: Great comments, thank you both. It seems we are ever in motion, yet most of the physics formula we use today don't take this into account. Still, to me it would be very interesting to see what happens in space if a similar experiment is reproduced, at least if two extremely massive balls were taken into deep space for a test where they had no motion relative to the observable universe. I understand both your points, but I still wish I could see the result of that test.

Comment: @Alexandru We don't "fail" to take motion into account, what we do is predict how relative motion changes in time based on what it current is.  Because that's what we can measure and what we can predict. It is unfair to say we failed to take into account something that can't be measured, when what we did is used the available information and made detailed, testable predictions.

Comment: @Alexandru: Since the observable universe is expanding and is therefore in motion how can anything not be in motion?

Comment: @slebetman Because, simply put, "motion" is a nonsense word if you don't say what you're in motion relative to. Motion *is* relative. If you're on Earth and I'm on a rocket you might say I'm moving, but it's just as easy for me to say I'm sitting perfectly still in my chair and watching the Earth fly by. On Earth you can pick a spot on the ground and note that you move from *this* spot to *that* spot but in space it doesn't work like that. The universe is, as far as we can tell, homogeneous, so there's no frame to measure movement against; you can only measure relative to other objects.

Comment: @qweilun, et. al. Actually, I don't think that you *can* meaningfully talk about motion "*relative to the observable universe*".  My understanding is that *we* are always at the center of the observable universe, because we are the observer.  If so, then motion relative to the observable universe, is just motion relative to ourselves.

Comment: It takes a vast amount of propulsion energy to stop motion relative to the sun (because anything launched from Earth starts with Earth's speed in solar orbit). There's little reason to believe the sun's position is a preferred reference frame (rather than any of billions or other stars, or the position of my left elbow), so no one has spent the hundreds of millions of dollars it would take to do that particular experiment.

Answer (score 25):

Your concern seems to be that the law of gravity might depend on whether the two bodies are moving relative to a third, external reference frame...

For example, you could do the Cavendish experiment in a lab in a University basement. Then you could load all the apparatus on a train and repeat the experiment while the train was rolling along (assuming no vibration and bends and jolts). You wonder if the results might be different, am I right?

I think you'd find there would be no difference and here's why:

Take a brick and count up all the protons and neutrons in it. Using the mass of the particles from particle physics, calculate the mass of the brick. Keep it stationary on the Earth and weigh it. This gives you the gravitational force due to the mass of the Earth.

Now watch the Moon as it orbits the Earth. Calculate the gravitational force that is required for the Moon to orbit as it does.

Taking account of the fact that the Moon is further away than the brick, check if the two results for the strength of the gravitational field are the same.

If they are, then the gravitational strength doesn't care if the object being attracted is moving (Moon) or stationary (brick).

Comment: This is actually the best answer I think, because it proposes a very simple mechanism that experimentally refutes the proposal. You look at the relative difference of "Cavendishish" attractions for two lab-stationary balls and two lab-moving balls.

Comment: Isn't that essentially the Michelson-Morley experiment, except they used the Earth's rotation around both its axis and the sun in place of a train.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I can't help but wonder - could the gravitational effects of the moon have affected the Cavendish experiment?

Comment: What about the gravitational effects of the Sun? We're talking about very small forces here. Can a torsion balance actually rule those out? If not then, it would mean that G is not a valid gravitational constant. It may be valid on or around Earth, but what experiments have proven that it is valid everywhere? On top of this, are all the masses of other planets that we have calculated based on G? Because if so, their calculated surface gravity might not be the same as their experimental surface gravity might be.

Answer (score 10):

The first measurement of the gravitational constant was done by  Henry Cavendish in a lab, in which the gravitational force between two lead balls was measured. They weren't moving. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment

Comment: Yes they were! They just weren't moving relative to one another.

Comment: Every object in the universe is moving with respect to something else. They were attracted to each other in their own "stationary" reference frame.

Comment: I'm going to ask you some questions, but please don't take them personally, they are just for my own understanding. What are some of the theories that make a claim that no single object in the universe is stationary relative to, well, the universe? Also, why can this experiment as a whole overlook the fact that these two objects are in motion? Suppose for a moment that gravity is actually proportional not to mass, but to motion and mass together, and since all objects in the universe that I can think of that have a force of gravity are in motion, how can this be overlooked?

Comment: *"What are some of the theories that make a claim that no single object in the universe is stationary relative to, well, the universe?"* Newtonian physics (really starting with Galileo) and Einsteinian physics. Ernst Mach had some very interesting things to say on these matters around the turn of the 20th century, which influenced Einstein very much.

Comment: @dmckee If you can provide some links to the relative portions of their theories that discuss masses always being in motion, I would love to take a read, because something doesn't add up here, and I think the Cavendish experiment has overlooked a key piece of the puzzle that it should not have. I also feel like this experiment should be attempted again, but not on Earth, not with the same instrumentation of course, and with a great attempt to make the two massive objects being tested have as little motion as possible relative to the universe.

Comment: @Alexandru There is no such thing as "motion relative to the universe", it doesn't mean anything in physics. So if you use that term, you need to explain what you mean by it in physics terms. Perhaps relative to CMBR, as measured with red/blue shift?

Comment: @Alexandru: Brian Greene's "Fabric of the Cosmos" has a very well-written chapter (Chapter 3, to be exact) on this aspect of and the development of our understanding of spacetime. Perhaps it can help you grasp the concepts involved better than a physics-oriented answer.

Comment: @Alexandru Besides the point that there is absolute reference frame to say that things are moving w.r.t. the "universe" (positions can only be measured in reference to other positions) - if the law of gravity was proportional to mass times velocity, you could try to derive Kepler's laws and you would fail.

Comment: @jwimberley on Earth you do have the Coriolis effect, which does depend on your velocity relative to its surface.

Comment: "*Newtonian physics (really starting with Galileo)*" - Not Galileo. There is no preferred frame in the Galilean spacetime. This is its only difference from the Newtonian spacetime. See the second part of the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588492/what-is-a-mathematical-definition-of-the-maxwellian-spacetime

Answer (score 10):

The concept of a body being "completely without motion in space" is thoroughly discredited, and you really should take the other responders seriously on this point.

According to Einstein's General Theory of Relativity, the nearest we can come to this state is by being in gravitational free fall. But now the Solar System provides the perfect test that you are looking for: every non-artificial body in the Solar System is in gravitational free fall. (OK, there are exceptions: for instance, when a small comet approaches the Sun, it might emit enough gases to measurably change its trajectory. But this is a side issue.)

In short, what you are looking for does not exist. It's like asking whether anybody has travelled to the edge of the world to find out whether the world has an edge or not. "But...but nobody's ever *gone* there! How can we know it doesn't exist if nobody's ever gone there?"

Answer (score 3):

The biggest point is of course that all motion is relative, as many have pointed out. Even barring that, pretending that we live in Copernican times and assuming that the Sun is the center of the universe, the question posits that the force of gravity might be proportional to mass and velocity. This would mean something like
$$
\vec F\left( \vec v, \hat r, \frac{Mm}{r^2} \right)
$$
Terms like $\vec v \cdot \hat r$ and $\vec v \times \hat r$ are ruled out by the observation that $\vec F$ is parallel to $\hat r$. So, we have 
$$
\vec F = -G' \frac{v}{c} \frac{Mm}{r^2} \hat r
$$
where $G'$ isn't necessarily the $G$ measured in the Cavendish experiment (constraints will be derived). Since the sun and the orbiting object might be moving in our Copernican/Newtonian "universe", for the solar system this becomes
$$
\vec F = -G' \frac{\left| \vec v + \vec v_{orb} \right|}{c} \frac{Mm}{r^2} \hat r
$$
There are two simplifying limits, where the sun's velocity is 0 or much greater than the planet's orbital velocity.

**Case 1: Sun's "universe" velocity is zero**

Then, for an orbiting planet, the acceleration is
$$
\vec F = - \frac{G'Mm}{c} \frac{|\vec v|}{r^2} \hat r
$$
This is still a centripetal force (with no torque, $\vec r \times \vec F = 0$). So, it works out that angular momentum $L$ is conserved. So, the effective one dimensional DE is, since $L = m r^2 \omega$ and $v = r \omega$,
$$
\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2} = - \frac{G'M}{c} \frac{r \omega}{r^2} + \frac{L^2}{mr^3} = \left(L^2 - \frac{G'ML}{mc} \right) \frac{1}{r^3}
$$
This is directly integrable! Defining
$$
A = L^2 - \frac{G'ML}{mc},
$$
the solution (starting from a point where dr/dt = 0) is
$$
r(t) = r_0 \sqrt{1 + \frac{At^2}{r_0^4}}
$$
Three subclasses:

*Subcase 1: $L > G'M/mc$ so that $A > 0$*

This describes an orbit spiraling away to infinity, horribly contradicting observation.

*Subcase 2: $L < G'M/mc$ so that $A < 0$*

This describes an orbit spiraling in. Also bad.

*Subcase 3: $L = G'M/mc$ so that $A = 0$*

Fine, a falling straight trajectory.

So, this horribly fails.

**Case 2: The Sun's "universe" velocity is large**

The orbital velocity is much less than the speed of light, but the sun's might not beso expanding in series
$$
\frac{\left| \vec v_{sun} + \vec v_{orb} \right|}{c}
\approx \frac{v_{sun}}{c} \left(1 + \frac{\hat v_{sun} \cdot \vec v_{orb}}{v_{sun}} \right)
$$
This leads to two terms, the first of which is just Newton's laws (absorbing $G'v_{sun}/c$ into $G$) and the second of which is a perturbation:
$$
\vec F = - \left(1 + \frac{\hat v_{sun} \cdot \vec v_{orb}}{v_{sun}} \right) \frac{GMm}{r^2}
$$
I don't intend on solving this more complicated equation, but I'll point out that if you did so (analytically or numerically), you could use observational data to put constraints on $v_{sun}$, which I believe would be severe.

Edit: This one sneaks through to lowest order if you assume that the sun's motion is normal to the solar system's plane; you'd have to look at nasty second order terms.

Comment: What if its not orbital velocity that I mean to take into account, but if I were to postulate that a massive object's spin on its own axis is what defines its gravity, and that orbital velocity is a byproduct of competition for space due to two definining gravities of massive objects trying to compete for a remote space?

Comment: I'd point out to you that Mercury and the Moon are tidally locked, with their periods of rotation equal to their periods of revolution, and Venus as well has a very long day.

Comment: That's a great counter-point. Although Mercury is not tidally locked to the Sun (it was originally thought that it was, but I looked it up and it turns out that its not)...what if it is just a coincidence that the Moon happens to spin at a rate such that it's considered to be tidally locked? Can we really know for sure that this disproves my postulation?

Comment: This concept could explain quantum entanglement, whereby an electron's spin is what tries to define its space, and competes with an entangled electron that is on the same axis, such that it transmits this energy for space competition through light in such a way to make the other, tangled electron, spin the opposite way. Thereby spin defines gravity and light is a measure of space competition (or quantum entanglement, depending on how you want to look at it).

Comment: In much the same concept, light would heat you up because the spin of massive particles driving it try to affect your own body's stationary particles, but your body's stationary particles are resistant to this spin because of the dynamics of the spin of your body's molecules. So heat would become a measure of resistance to spin. Magnetism could be explained through spin as well, and so forth.

Comment: @Alexandru TBH, it seems that you really aren't paying attention to anything anyone is telling you. Wondering if something is possible (gravity dependence on velocity) and being curious is good, but refusing to listen and be critical of your own ideas is not. Your new postulate about orbital speeds is absurd. If you are serious about your proposal, why don't you compare the rotational speeds of planets with the force of gravity that binds them to the sun? You'll see that there is no relationship. It's easy for things to make sense in your head by ignoring reality.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't mean to sound arrogant. This is just me being curious. I meant no harm by what I said, and I didn't mean to be rude to you or anything like that. Please don't take it personally. You seem to be good at math, for me its been a few years since university and I've forgotten a lot from my old quantum mechanics courses or physics courses, so I wanted to talk to you about it, to see what such a theory could look like. I know that the big thing in physics is the EPR paradox, and I'd like to find curious reasons to explain it.

Comment: Perhaps if the current models don't explain everything, they need to be adjusted in order to make a unified theory. Probably they are accurate to a certain degree, but maybe we have overlooked something in physics, something that needs to be added back into those equations.

Comment: The best proof for anything is mother nature, and I think we've done experiments in order to determine some results, but the experiments were biased by a few small things that we didn't take into account. That same bias would contribute to a system of equations that are believed to be true because they all work for most observable conditions since those observable conditions also contain the same bias, but the difficulty of conducting such experiments without the bias is hard, and because of that we have chosen to continually try proving ourselves true, but our proofs include the same bias.

Comment: The data for rotational speed of planets is out there, and so is their masses and  centripetal accelerations (a = v^2/r), to get observed force F = mv^2/r, and G and the mass of the Sun,to get the predicted force. You can and should compare these yourself

Comment: But I can't help but wonder how other planets' gravities have been measured or just calculated...if its using the same formulae and those formulae are wrong...then that would make my calculations wrong when they may actually be right. In other words, what planets' gravities in the Solar System have actually been measured experimentally, as oppose to calculated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20427/discussion-between-jwimberley-and-alexandru).

Comment: I feel like spin and light are one and the same, I just can't prove it yet but I'm going to try really hard. Quote: "New measurements from ESA’s Venus Express spacecraft shows that Venus’ rotation rate is about 6.5 minutes slower than previous measurements taken 16 years ago by the Magellan spacecraft." (http://www.universetoday.com/93494/is-venus-rotation-slowing-down/) More evidence, and notably, Venus is the only planet in our Solar System that stands out with its retrograde axial spin as well as retrograde motion.

Comment: Being the brightest planet, it means it's also the most resistant to sunlight. As a result, the Sun may actually be trying to force it to spin...the other way.

Answer (score 1):

I think Cavendish demonstrated this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment

Comment: This is, in fact, and example of the very bad category of answer known as "[link only](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/859/are-link-only-answers-acceptable)". It could be improved considerable by describing the basics here.